# SSH connect problem via Wifi: I can connect on my Android (JuiceSSH), but cannot connect via CMD on windows

Tags: wifi, ssh, pi-zero-w

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W which I have Raspberry Pi OS Lite as image.

I have preconfigured Pi as headless with Wifi, and with SSH enabled.

If I connect via JuiceSSH on my android phone, I get access the the Pi. They are on  same network.
If I try the same from CMD or Putty on Windows 10, which is also on the same network, I dont see the pi, and I cant connect. Nothing suggests I can see it in `ipconfig`. I have also done an `ipconfig /flushdns`.

I connect via SSH with address `raspberrypi` and username `pi` and pass `raspberry` (std. setup). So nothing has been configured in this part.

I have no idea what to try now, since I can access it via my Android phone, which then suggests everything is working correctly. Using `raspberrypi.local` doesn't help.

All suggestions much appreciated

Comment: Can you ping the IP address from the windows machine?

Comment: No ping either.

Comment: There's probably not much anyone can add then; the problem is with the router or windows. How about pinging the windows IP from the Pi?  Just to clarify: by "IP address" I meant the dot decimal (192.168...), not a hostname.

Comment: Windows doesn't understand mdns which means it won't be able to resolve reaspberrypi.local.

Login to your Pi with the route that does work and run..  ip addr  find your IP address.   Then try that from your windows box instead of the mdns name.